# Getting a „Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘[a]’...“ error

Tags: haskell

I'm a Haskell beginner and I'm having a trouble with this piece of code. The task is to make a BFS function for the given data type. I've tried many variations, but the problem essentially remains the same: type mismatch.

```
data OrdTree a = OrdTree a [OrdTree a] 
             deriving (Show)

root :: OrdTree a -> a
root (OrdTree x _) = x

children :: OrdTree a -> [OrdTree a]
children (OrdTree _ x) = x

bfsTreeList ::  OrdTree a ->  [a]
bfsTreeList ot = (map root [ot]) ++ (map bfsTreeList (children ot))
```

DFS seems to work just fine:

```
dfsTreeList ::  OrdTree a ->  [a]
dfsTreeList ot = root ot : concat (map dfsTreeList (sons ot))
```

Comment: `map f [x]` is `[f x]`.

Comment: `[x] ++` is `x :`.

Comment: SIde note: consider defining `OrdTree` using the record syntax, in order to get accessors `root` and `children` "for free".

Comment: If your bfsTreeList wasn't a type error, it would be identical to dfsTreeList.

Comment: `map bfsTreeList` has the type `[OrdTree a] -> [[a]]` - but you state that the return type (and hence the inferred type of `map bfsTreeList ...`) is `[a]`, so you get a type mismatch between `[a]` and `[[a]]` - you use `concat` in `dfsTreeList` , perhaps that would help here?

Answer (score 1):

Try thinking in terms of levels of the tree. What is a level? It is a list of subtrees.

```
type Level a = [OrdTree a]
```

Next you'll need a function that, given a level, produces the next level. You may find the function `concatMap` useful here but it is not strictly necessary.

```
nextLevel :: Level a -> Level a
nextLevel = ...
```

After you have this, you'll want a function that, given a tree, produces a list of its levels. This will probably be an infinite list (since the next level of an empty level is again an empty level), but after a certain point it will only be populated with empty levels. Here you might find the function `iterate` useful.

```
levels :: OrdTree a -> [Level a]
levels = ...
```

Finally, you're able to construct your `bfsTreeList` function using these pieces. You'll produce a list of levels from your tree using `levels`, then you'll cut off the portion that only contains empty levels making the list finite, then you'll concatenate the list and retrieve the values stored:

```
bfsTreeList :: OrdTree a -> [a]
bfsTreeList = map root . concat . takeWhile (not . null) . levels
```

Here's an example tree you can use as a test case:

```
exampleTree :: OrdTree Int
exampleTree = OrdTree 1 [ OrdTree 2 [ OrdTree 5 []
                                    , OrdTree 6 []]
                        , OrdTree 3 [ OrdTree 7 []
                                    , OrdTree 8 [OrdTree 9 []]]
                        , OrdTree 4 []]
```

The result should look like this:

```
λ. bfsTreeList exampleTree 
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```